# Integrate Python plugin in APISIX Instance

Tags: python, plugins, apache-apisix

I require your help. I am trying to create a Python plugin for my apisix server. I have followed the apisix documentation for the Python plugin from https://apisix.apache.org/docs/python-plugin-runner/next/getting-started/. but I do not get a clear idea of how to develop the plugin and how to use it. I have followed the steps but I am getting the error (please refer to the image). I am not sure how to resolve this issue.
I would really appreciate it if anybody can help me with this. [Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwlqZ.png)

Comment: Please include the full code in your question instead of using images.

Comment: You mean the full plugin code? @LaassairiAbdellah